# Tasklist replacement for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, task, add-on

I would like to use the task-list in Visual Studio but it really lacks almost any useful feature a task-list should provide. So I use [Todo-List](http://www.abstractspoon.com/) externally, to keep track of the things I need to get done. Would be nice to have it all in one place.

So does anyone know of a cool replacement Add-On for the tasklist in Visual Studio?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the [**FogBugz add-in**](http://our.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W984) for Visual Studio 2005 and 2008?

This requires a [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/) account hosted either locally or by Fog Creek. A free Student and Startup version is [available](https://shop.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/default.asp?sCategory=HOSTEDFB&sStep=stepEnterEmailAddress&HFBnForm=1).

Comment: Probably you forgot to mention that this does require the FogBugz server.

Answer (score 4):

Assumed: Visual Studio 2008 + ReSharper

ReSharper->Windows->ToDo Explorer

E-

Answer (score 2):

For semi-immediate programming tasks I use TODO comments in code and ReSharper for Visual Studio to view them.

For longer-term tasks I use Team Foundation Server to record work items.

For non-programming tasks I use Google Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the task list in Visual Studio by clicking 
TOOLS --> OPTIONS --> ENVIRONMENT --> TASK LIST

In the Token List you can add more tokens specific to what you want to call your tasks.

For example.. I have an EDITING token set up so in any module, class or method that I'm working on I just add the  ' EDITING: (Name of whatever method ect..)  comment and I can quickly see where I left off and get back too it by double clicking.

[image]

Here are a few other tokens I find useful...
[image]

If you would like more advanced project and code tracking you should check out Visual Studio Online. It's free for upto 5 users. 
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an add-on (I use [Remember The Milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/) externally), but I think you are onto a good idea there.

Answer (score 0):

We use Team Foundation Server at work - it is a really superb product, but too expensive for smaller teams.

Out of work I'm looking to use CountersSoft Gemini (http://countersoft.com/home.aspx) which has good VS integration and is competitive when looking at the hosted version with unlimited users.