# Visual Studio ToDo.Who's using?

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, todo

I'm interesting with statistic and motivation of using task list in VS. Why are you use it or not? Some people i asked even want a tool, that can synchronize VS ToDo with Outlook. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you can use Todos for:

1. Remember that you must do something like **"Todo: implement this interface"**
2. To mark a line/block of code as instruction for another coder if your are code in a team like **"Todo: you can use foo instead of bar because ..."**
3. If you review your code you can mark any code that he can be improved like **"Todo: use Linq instead of foreach"**

You can replace the default tasklist-window from visual studio with plugins:

- [Tasklist replacement for Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94864/tasklist-replacement-for-visual-studio)
- http://genne-develop.com/

Comment: Ok, so would you like to see those todo in Outlook?

Comment: Myself not. But Outlook has a tasklist and i think someone could be wish to see this todos in outlook.

Comment: I think the better way is to make an Visual Studion Todo Window Replacemend like this from genne-develop and make at each todo an syncoption option for sync with outlook tasklist and outlook calender. so you can spezifie a date at this the todo sould be processed.

Answer (score 1):

I used TODO for two purposes:

1. To mark enhancements that can be
   done at a later stage. So whenever,
   there is slack time, you can pick
   one of them out of your pending TODO
   list.
2. Things that are still need to be done while I am coding - so that I can re-visit those places and fix them. This is something like bookmarks except they are visible to other folks even if I forgot to fix them.

I use TODO comment syntax - it's there in code and not in .suo file as mentioned by Benjol.

Answer (score 0):

I use TODO sparingly - only when I have something that I'm not the master of (something another team-member is working on etc.). I treat it as I treat bugs - max 5 at any time.

If I need scaffolding - I create temporary classes with Fake as a prefix in the class-name.

I guess, I don't want my production code to also act as my scrum-board/task-list.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be wary of about Task Lists in VS is that they are stored in the `.suo` file, which (I believe) [most people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644653/which-files-in-a-visual-c-studio-project-dont-need-to-be-versioned/1644693#1644693) tend to exclude from source control.